# Why does Rails i18n-active_record gem interpolates string with '--- value \n\n'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am using Rails i18n-active_record gem and when I save translation from web interface Ralis interpolates plain string and inserts `--- value \n\n` into translations value column and `--- []\n`, so I if i lookup for translation through `Translation` model I get `--- value \n\n`, but if do `I18n.t('key')` I get actual `value`, any clue why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This format is YAML – default "coder" for serialized attribute. It turns out that while I'm using i18n-active_record gem, which serializes value and interpolations column, I also created my own `Translation` model, which hasn't

```
serialize :value
serialize :interpolations, Array
```

So the problem was that when I save some translations they are serialized by i18n-active_record gem, [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/active_record/translation.rb), but when I retrieve them they don't. So the solution was <strike>to add the above serialize calls to my Translation model</strike> to inherit my Translation model from `I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation`.

[This article](http://rubyjunky.com/rails-activerecord-serialize.html) helped me to understand  that format was serialization.